# Call function when value of textfield = 3 or 9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function when a value of textfield changes to 3 or 9.

Different functions are changing the value of this textfield, but I want to call another function when the value of field changes to 3 or 9.

Here is the fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k3Q9k/20/

Now the function should not be called from inside the function which are changing the value of field. The function taking decission should be independent. Some thing like this:

**JS:**

```
$('.increment').click(function () {
    var currentValue = $('#category').val();
    var incrementedValue = parseInt(currentValue) + parseInt(1);
    $('#category').val(incrementedValue);
    // Check function should not be called from here 
});

$('.decrement').click(function () {
    var currentValue = $('#category').val();
    var incrementedValue = parseInt(currentValue) - parseInt(1);
    $('#category').val(incrementedValue);
    // Check function should not be called from here
});

$('#category').change(function () {
    // Check function should be called from here because this is an independent function
    var currentValue = $('#category').val();
    if (currentValue == 3 || currentValue == 9) {
        alert("Got it");
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="1" >
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="increment" >Increment</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="decrement" >Decrement</a>
```

**NOTE: Those functions which are changing my field values are not accessible to me. So i have to write a blind sided code, which will totally take decision on its own**

Answer (score 5):

You have binded the logic to a change event handler, but when the value of an input field is changed programatically the change event is not triggered. That is the problem.

One possible solution is to trigger the change event manually after the value is changed programatically as given below

```
$('#category').val(incrementedValue).change();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g5K2P/)

Comment: You're so fast =D This has to be like the 50th time you beat me to an answer! I like the challenge!

Comment: I cant change my existing function. The function should be independent for taking decision

Comment: Those functions which are changing my field values are not accessible to me. So i have to write a blind sided code, which will totally take decision on its own

Comment: Here again the function is independent(the logic)... but the question is how the function will know the value has changed

Comment: Please read the note in my question. I cant change my function. The should be independent

Comment: @CodeHunter other solution could be to use a timer based sweep to check whether the value is met

Comment: hmm so there is no way we can take decision on what value changes to

Comment: You can do a hackish way by checking every second or so if the value has changed and then do it. The ideal way is of course to trigger change programmatically since you're changing the value programmatically.

Comment: @Sanchit I've already suggested it in the comments... but comes with its own problem like how you make sure that if the value is `4` and not changed after that next execution of the function should ignore it

Comment: I know, I didn't think he got it. :3 So I defined "timer based sweep" using more words.

Comment: Yea better than the prevoius

Answer (score 0):

You can also use setInterval  to check teh value periodically.  Something like:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k3Q9k/28/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="1" >
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="increment" >Increment</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="decrement" >Decrement</a>
```

**jQuery/javascript:**

```
$('.increment').click(function (){
    var currentValue = $('#category').val();  
    var incrementedValue = parseInt(currentValue)+parseInt(1);
    $('#category').val(incrementedValue);
});

$('.decrement').click(function (){
    var currentValue = $('#category').val();  
    var incrementedValue = parseInt(currentValue)-parseInt(1);
    $('#category').val(incrementedValue);
});

var chk = setInterval(chkValue, 2000);

function chkValue() {
    var currentValue = $('#category').val(); 
    if(currentValue==4){
       alert("Got it"); 
       clearInterval(chk);
    }
}
```

***Note that the interval is checked every 2000 millisecond (2 secs). You could also set it for more frequent checking, for eg. 500 (half sec).***